# How to solve $z^3=52+47i$ in the first quadrant?

Tags: complex-numbers

Can anybody help me get the result for this equation? It lies in the first quadrant of the complex plane.

> $$z^3=52+47i$$

Thank you

Comment: This is not a homework solutions providers. Explain what difficulties you have and you will get help. Hint: rewrite the equation in polar form (that is, in terms of modulus and argument).

Comment: The result is $4+i$. Follow GFR's advice to get it.

Comment: I tried that but it gives me some weird numbers

Comment: Show us your work, then we can detect the problem. The other two roots are actually "weird".

Comment: Thank you. What did you get for |z|? is it 4913^1/2?

Comment: No, this is the absolute value of $z^3$.

Comment: The third root of $4913^{1/2}$ is ...

Comment: Another small hint : For the argument, you have to calculate an arctan and divide by $3$

Comment: Thank you, that was probably a problem (miss calculated |z|). I will try again when I come home.

Answer (score 1):

> **Tip:** A good way to solve these complex-number equations is to substitute $z$ with $a+bi$.

---

Letting $z=a+bi$, we get$$(a+bi)^3=52+47i\tag{1}$$Using the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) on the LHS, or $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$, we get $a^3+3a^2bi-3ab^2-b^3i=52+47i$. Grouping the terms together in $a+bi$ form, we get $$(a^3-3ab^2)+(3a^2b-b^3)i=52+47i\tag{2}$$
And equating corresponding coefficients, we get $$a^3-3ab^2=52\\3a^2b-b^3=47$$ with $a=4,b=1$ the solution that satisfies your requirement: $z$ lies in the first quadrant.

---

Comment: You did rather pluck that solution out of thin air! How did you solve those two equations?

Comment: @TonyK From $$a^3-3ab^2=52\\3a^2b-b^3=47$$, we can get $$47(a^3-3ab^2)=52(3a^2b-b^3)\implies 47a^3-156a^2b-141ab^2+52b^3=0\implies 47x^3-156x^2-141x+52=0\implies x=4\therefore a=4b$$Plugging $a=4b$ into any one of the equations in the original system gives $$(4b)^3-3(4b)b=52\implies b=1\\ \therefore b=1,a=4$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @TonyK Np... This may not be the most efficient thing to try on larger systems, but it works okay on two system of equations...